# How to easy extract data from file in python

Tags: python, text

I have a .txt file with variable information and I need to read it to transform them into objects, the file is written as lists and dictionaries, is there an easy way to read them in this format?

this is an example of what is written in the txt:

```
[
 {
  "arg1":value1,
  "arg2":value2
 },
 {
  "arg1":value3,
  "arg2":value4
 },
]
```

Comment: What are the values? Are they really as shown, without quotes around them?

Comment: What you've shown is not valid JSON. Where is this data coming from, and do you have control over the source?

Answer (score 1):

This is valid JSON; use the `json` module.

```
import json

with open('file.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

Comment: Aah, it's not quite valid JSON because of that last comma and non-quoted non-number values. I'll edit or delete based on clarifications.

Comment: Answer first, then ask questions?

Comment: @martineau, not intentionally. I answered, then realized a problem and asked for clarification. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could interpret your input data as [`yaml` format](http://yaml.org/):

```
import yaml 

with open('data.txt') as file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(file)
```

#### Result

```
[{'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'}, {'arg1': 'value3', 'arg2': 'value4'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only lists and dictionaries you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). For your example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> content = open('input.txt').read()
>>> lst = ast.literal_eval(content)
>>> lst
[{'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'}, {'arg1': 'value3', 'arg2': 'value4'}]
```

Note that I also quoted the values, otherwise there would be an error when evaluating the string. But if the values are numbers it will work normally.